# Radius of a random walk

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

Let’s consider a random walk X(t) starting from the centre of a 2D grid. Following its most recent trajectory, the random walk moves one step forward with probability 0.8, turn left with probability 0.1 and turn right with probability 0.1. Turns are performed at the same position.

How to estimate the radius of the random walk after n steps, ie, the distance from X(0) to X(n) ?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that a pretty good (asymptotic) estimate would be 0.8$n$, since 80% of the moves would have been spent moving forwards and on average, left and right turns occur just as often and so roughly will cancel each other out.

Comment: Are the turns in place, or do they include a step?

Comment: Paw88789: The turns are in place.

Comment: Thanks Isky. Does the approximation account for moves like step-step-left-left-step-step ? Moves that bring back to the original position?

Comment: You can always simulate it 10.000 times and see what happens :)

Comment: Ant: true :) but I am thinking about more general cases.

Comment: As a functional equation let $p(n, x, y, d)$ be the probability of landing at $(x, y)$ after $n$ steps with direction $d$.

We have initial $p(0, 0, 0, 1) = 1$ and $p(0, x, y, d) = 0$. Then all other steps are described by

$$p(n, x, y, d) = 0.1 \cdot (p(n-1, x, y, id) + p(n-1, x, y, -id)) +  \\
0.8\cdot(p(n-1, x-1, y, 1)) + p(n-1, x + 1, y, -1) + p(n, x, y-1, i) + p(n, x, y + 1, -i)) $$

Comment: This walk can be understood as a variable speed random walk, which tells that it diffuses at the speed proportional to $\sqrt{n}$ (in average sense).

Comment: Thanks Sangchul. Is there a mathematical way of calculating it as function of the probabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but I ran some simulations :

For $100$ steps (simulated $1000$ times), the average Euclidean distance was about $25$.

For $1000$ steps (simulated $1000$ times), the average distance was about $75$.

For $10000$ steps (simulated $100$ times), the average distance was about $250$.

This seems to suggest that the distance on average is (approximately) proportional to $\sqrt{n}$ where $n$ is the number of steps.